# How to generate correct ordering of files with typescript?

Tags: typescript

Consider two typescript files:

File `a.ts`:

```
module SomeModule {
  export class AClass {
  }
}
```

File `b.ts`:

```
module SomeModule {
  export var aValue = new AClass();
}
```

If you compile them using `tsc -out out.js b.ts a.ts`, it compiles without error and `out.js` has the contents:

```
var SomeModule;
(function (SomeModule) {
    SomeModule.aValue = new SomeModule.AClass();
})(SomeModule || (SomeModule = {}));
var SomeModule;
(function (SomeModule) {
    var AClass = (function () {
        function AClass() {
        }
        return AClass;
    })();
    SomeModule.AClass = AClass;
})(SomeModule || (SomeModule = {}));
```

This is a problem, as `SomeModule.AClass` is used before it is defined. Now the problem can be fixed by adding `///<reference path="a.ts" />` to the top of the `b.ts` file. This will ensure the `a.ts` is output before the `b.ts` file.

However, the project still compiles without warning without this line, so fixing this is a bit error prone. Worse, when used in a build script or using `gulp-typescript`, often the project will work fine initially without the line (due to the ordering being correct initially), but then start failing at random later on. So I'm looking for a way to ensure the file is in the correct order. Solutions I have thought of:

1. Get typescript to determine the file order based on the implicit references to other files.
2. Enforce references to other files, throwing an error if they are missing.

Unfortunately I couldn't get either to work. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Unfortunately I couldn't get either to work. Is there a solution to this

Don't use `--out` https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md. Instead use external modules: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've been researching it for a couple of hours, as using external modules was something I was avoiding (as I never needed the complexity before). Deciding between CommonJS, AMD, requirejs, browserify and webpack is pretty overwhelming. Do you have any suggestions as to what path to go down? The TypeStrong link is not helpful for this, and your youtube video using external modules, while very helpful, also doesn't use concatenation.

Comment: Can you post the tl:dr; of the advice in the video?  If I watched a 10min video for every stackoverflow answer I read I'd die of old-age before I finished the Typescript tutorial...